# UITableViewController and ViewWillAppear issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

In my iOS app I have a `UITableViewController` with some custom cells containing `UITextView` each one.
The reason I decided to use the `UITableViewController` instead of a normal `UIViewController` was because I wanted to automatically move up the view when the keyboard appear and it was working great at the beginning but when I needed to override the `-viewWillAppear` method it stopped working. Does anyone knows how to fix this issue? Or can anyone explain to me why this is happening?

Comment: didn't you forget to call `[super viewWillAppear:animated]` in `viewWillAppear:` ? Most likely UITableViewController subscribes to keyboard notifications in `viewWillAppear:` and unsubscribes in `viewWillDisappear:`

Comment: Yes, that worked pretty well. Thanks!

Comment: @PetroKorienev: you should answer this question (not comment) to get full reward :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Didn't you forget to call `[super viewWillAppear:animated]` in `viewWillAppear:` ? Most likely UITableViewController subscribes to keyboard notifications in `viewWillAppear:` and unsubscribes in `viewWillDisappear:`

Comment: It is also explicitly written in the documentation: "If you override this method, you must call super at some point in your implementation."

Comment: It's for `UIViewController`... But judging from personal experience (there are no objective reasons to believe me!) not calling `[super viewWillAppear:animated]` on `UIViewController` subclasses causes no problems at all. However if we talk about `UITableViewController`, we have kind of problems, like Fernando Reynoso faced.

Comment: Thanks @PetroKorienev. This answer solve my problem. And I'm totally agree with your comment.

Answer (score 1):

must call

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

Most likely UITableViewController subscribes to keyboard notifications in viewWillAppear: and unsubscribes in viewWillDisappear:

Comment: Did you just copy and paste someone else's comment as an answer? Shame on you.

Comment: Shahab if you are going to move a comment into an answer, please include attribution to the solution. In this case, you should add that [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24348912/uitableviewcontroller-and-viewwillappear-issue#comment37645775_24348912) answered the question and you moved it to an answer.  @PetroKorienev if you are going to provide a comment that could be a useful answer, then you can't blame people for moving it to an answer.  Comment can easily be deleted and your "comment solution" would be gone.

Comment: @bluefeet, following this logic answer can be also deleted easily. Even accepted ones, i think.